# invalid target release 1.8

Tags: java, maven, openshift

I was try to deploy my application on the OPENSHIFT, but maven can't compile it with error:

> invalid target release 1.8

my "build" action_hook:

```
export JAVA_HOME="${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}jdk1.8.0_05"
export PATH=${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}jdk1.8.0_05/bin:$PATH
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
java -version
mvn package -s .openshift/settings.xml -DskipTests=true
```

RESULT

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
[devlt-chernihiv.rhcloud.com repo]\> mvn package -s .openshift/settings.xml -DskipTests=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building LaserTag 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ sector ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ sector ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /var/lib/openshift/5601634589f5cfa11000006a/app-root/runtime/repo/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.018s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 22 11:27:06 EDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/113M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project sector: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

then I use this script and see the problem:

```
export JAVA_HOME=${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}jdk1.8.0_05
export PATH=${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}jdk1.8.0_05/bin:$PATH
java -version
```

> java version "1.8.0_05"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

```
mvn --version | grep 'Java home'
```

> Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.85/jre

Java Home was changed, but maven ignore new java home. Please help.

Comment: What does your `${HOME}/.mavenrc` and your `MAVEN_OPTS` say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use WildFly catrtridge. This cartridge has all what you need. Java8, spring boot triggers, and admin panel.

Comment: I would disagree as long as you want to use the free service since it will quickly run over 1Gb of quota usage.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the java8 marker in your .openshift/markers folder for your project, that should help get maven to use the correct version.  That is assuming that you are using one of the standard java cartridges and not a DIY cartridge.

Comment: I have only java7 marker in openshift markers chooser.

Comment: I created java8 marker, but it did not help, any suggestions?

Comment: Did you also remove the Java7 marker?  If not, the cartridge will still use Java 7, since I believe that marker is processed first.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your mvn command is setting its own JAVA_HOME. Check the contents of 'mvn' to see what it is doing.