# Deploy JSP Webapplication on Tomcat7 (via OpenShift with GIT)

Tags: java, tomcat7, openshift, war

I have build a web appliation containing a Spring MVC project with a mysql database and a tomcat7 server. This is now published to GIT of OpenShift.
But starting the server takes only 160ms and I can clearly see nothing is being loaded really.

How do I do a real deployment and connect the Openshift Tomcat to my project?
I can code, but deployment-wise I am not a smart bulb.

My GIT repository looks like this:
[image: GitPicture1]

What is wrong?

**EDIT:**
As requested the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.afterguard</groupId>
  <artifactId>SailPlanner</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>sailplanner</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openshift</groupId>
        <artifactId>openshift-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
            version="3.0">
  <display-name>SailPlanner</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>  

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>sailplanner</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sailplanner</servlet-name>
<!--     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> -->
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/admin</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/admin/save</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/admin/delete</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/calendar_race</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/calendar_cruise</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/blog</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/blog/submit</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/blog/delete</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/event_feed</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/event/create</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/event/delete</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/event/crew/add</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/event/crew/remove</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/event/save</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/403</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/registration</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/inside/yacht/create</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/sailplanner-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param> 

        <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Git Push Log (of successful build):

```
Repository ssh://566ffc920c1e668c8a000049@afterguard-sailplanner.rhcloud.com/~/git/afterguard.git/

Stopping jbossews cartridge
Sending SIGTERM to jboss:333213 ...
Stopping MySQL 5.5 cartridge
Stopping PHPMyAdmin cartridge
Waiting for stop to finish
Waiting for stop to finish
Repairing links for 1 deployments
Building git ref 'master', commit 277c797
Using Maven mirror /var/lib/openshift/566ffc920c1e668c8a000049/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/config/settings.rhcloud.xml
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232336; 2012-12-18 14:36:37-0500)
Maven home: /usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
Found pom.xml... attempting to build with 'mvn --global-settings /var/lib/openshift/566ffc920c1e668c8a000049/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/config/settings.rhcloud.xml clean package -Popenshift -DskipTests'
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SailPlanner 0.8.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.pom

...A LOT OF BUILDING AND DOWNLOADING...

Downloaded: http://mirror.ops.rhcloud.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar (422 KB at 6105.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [SailPlanner] in [/var/lib/openshift/566ffc920c1e668c8a000049/app-root/runtime/repo/target/sailplanner]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/var/lib/openshift/566ffc920c1e668c8a000049/app-root/runtime/repo/WebContent]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [517 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /var/lib/openshift/566ffc920c1e668c8a000049/app-root/runtime/repo/WebContent/ROOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.062s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Dec 22 05:35:45 EST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/161M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Preparing build for deployment
Deployment id is 0f103f85
Activating deployment
Starting MySQL 5.5 cartridge
Starting PHPMyAdmin cartridge
Starting jbossews cartridge
Found 127.3.145.129:8080 listening port
-------------------------
Git Post-Receive Result: success
Activation status: success
Deployment completed with status: success
```

Tomcat log of OpenShift:

```
Dec 22, 2015 6:47:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1503 ms
Dec 22, 2015 6:47:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 22, 2015 6:47:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Dec 22, 2015 6:47:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.3.145.129-8080"]
Dec 22, 2015 6:47:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 251 ms
```

File Structure of ROOT.WAR, which is located in `/var/lib/openshift/<uuid>/app-root/runtime/repo/WebContent` :

```
|- META-INF
|- resources
|-- css
|-- fonts
|-- img
|-- js
|- WEB-INF
|-- classes
|--- com
|---- ...
|-- jsp
|--- index.jsp
|--- more jsp-sites
|-- jspf
|--- JSPF SITES I USE
|-- lib
|--- THE LIBS
|-- sailplanner-servlet.xml
|-- spring-datasource.xml
|-- spring-security.xml
|-- web.xml
```

Comment: can you post your `pom.xml` that is on your workspace folder?

Comment: Attached the ``pom.xml`` . But that is correct, I think. The problem is somehow the server not knowing where to find the explanation to run - I think.

Comment: You have these log which show that maven build uses java 7 currently (instead of java 8 configured in your maven *pom.xml*): *Maven home: /usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91/jre*

Comment: You should try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721278/invalid-target-release-1-8#answer-32721696 (I have updated my answer too)

Comment: That helped. Thanks...  No the build is successful, but the page is empty, see http://afterguard-sailplanner.rhcloud.com/

Comment: What do you have in your tomcat logs? can you share you war content somewhere?

Comment: Ok, I added the information. I still think the server is not starting my ``ROOT.war`` but just starting up.

Comment: I could not deploy Maven based Spring web MVC application on openshit. I have got this error: **Failed to fetch the input source.** I also have project war file on git-hub.There is no enough   documentation ( easy to understand ) for deploying application  on open-shit.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you have forgotten to add an openshift maven profile inside your *pom.xml* like bellow with proper *maven-war-plugin* configuration.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>travel</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then your application structure seems unusual. Usually to build a WAR with maven you put your webapp content in *src/main/webapp*, your resources in *src/main/resources* your WAR specific classes in *src/main/java*.

Take a look at *maven-war-plugin* user guide [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html).

Finally, check these documentations that could help you to unterstand how to deploy your application to Tomcat with OpenShift:

- [Host and Run Your Java Tomcat Application for Free on OpenShift’s PaaS](https://blog.openshift.com/run-your-java-tomcat-application-for-free-on-openshifts-paas/)
- [Tomcat Application Hosting](https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-overview.html)

If you follow properly steps described in these documentations, then any git push will trigger a build and application re-deployment to Tomcat

**EDIT**
As you have a build compilation issue now (Java 8 not supported), you should take a look at this answer: [invalid target release 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721278/invalid-target-release-1-8#answer-32721696)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I updated the pom and tried it once more. Building locally works with the pom and runs (except for the application in the main , instead of the one com.afterguard.

I attached the new ``Git Push Log`` to my post

Comment: That helped. Thanks...  No the build is successful, but the page is empty, see http://afterguard-sailplanner.rhcloud.com/

Comment: Check your deployed war content. It should have an index.html page at the root, or any other welcome page you configured in web.xml (*welcome-file-list* element)

Comment: No, that's not it. the web.xml contains it. No path is working to get to any files.

Comment: Could you check what is inside your tomcat webapps directory? (this is the directory where webapps are deployed). Then I don't see any index.html or index.jsp file in your ROOT.war content description. Are you sure you have such a file and it matches your welcome-file-list configuration? Finally could you update your pom with current version and openshift profile? Thanks

Comment: I added some more infos to the original post. The `index.jsp` is located in `WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp`. This is configured this way in my web.xml as you can see now above. I tried this `ROOT.war` on my local server and it works fine and starts the application and the index.jsp right away.
I have no idea, why OpenShift doesn't load my application. I see a blank page, not even a `Resource not Available` or other server message. Even changing the paths doesn't produce an error message.

Comment: In the openshift maven-profile provided in my answer, there is this configuration : `<outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>` that your current pom.xml misses. This configuration is mandatory, as according to the first openshift documentation link which is in my answer: *webapps directory: You should use this directory in case you want to do binary deployments on OpenShift i.e. you want to deploy a war file directly instead of pushing the source code.* Thus this profile allows to generate the war directly in this directory.

Comment: Ok, I did this too and changed `WebContent` to `webapps`.
Nothing changes: Still a blank page without content.

Comment: I tried it with a fresh new project, which I started to discuss now in this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454317/tomcat-startup-error-with-openshift
As I can't seem to get this working over the past week.
There I "only" run into a startup error -  more than I received in the old project... :-) *yeay*

Answer (score 2):

I have a JSP application on OpenShift Tomcat.
But all of my source code located in /src/main

Java src code in /src/main/java that means com.example.Main 's location is `<APP_NAME>/src/main/java/com/example/Main.java`

JSP src code in /src/main/webapp that means index.jsp 's location is `<APP_NAME>/src/main/webapp/index.jsp`

Comment: But there must be a way to change this. Especially as I have to connect to a mysql database anyhow...

Answer (score 2):

Have you actually performed a `git commit` and `git push`?

If so, can you dump the logs from `git push`.