# error while deploy on OpenShift

Tags: java, maven, openshift

I try to make a rest web service with java and I use *OpenShift* service for testing server.

in OpenShift I choose Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) as web server.

when I'm tring to push my files in to server, in maven build time, it give me these errors:

```
remote: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project operatorrail: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
remote: [ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/583387240c1e66c33cXXXXX/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/RestApi/Tools/tools.java:[5,16] error: cannot find symbol
remote: [ERROR] package java.util
remote: [ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/583387240c1e66c33cXXXXX/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/RestApi/Tools/tools.java:[35,25] error: cannot find symbol
remote: [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
remote: [ERROR] 
remote: [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote: [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote: [ERROR] 
remote: [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for /var/lib/openshift/583387240c1e66c33cXXXXXX/jbossews
remote: 
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
To ssh://XXXXXX-seyedaliroshan.rhcloud.com/~/git/restoprator.git/
   2233024..a2c2911  master -> master
```

It seems like the errors are about my *tools.java* file.

so here is my tools.java file's codes:

```
package RestApi.Tools;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

/**
 *  @file tools.java
 *  @brief this file contains some hasher like MD5.
 *
 *  @author Seyed Ali Roshan
 */
public class tools {

    public String md5(String text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(text.getBytes());

        byte byteData[] = md.digest();


        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0;i<byteData.length;i++) {
            String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xff & byteData[i]);
            if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append('0');
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    }

    public String[] conventToUserPass(String text) {
        String patternText = "(?i)Basic ";
        String hashedString = text.replaceFirst(patternText, "");

        byte[] unhased = Base64.getDecoder().decode(text);
        String finalText = new String(unhased);

        return finalText.split(":");
    }
}
```

I wonder because when I use command `mvn compile` in my PC there is no error and the project compile completely (without any error).

in errors there is a link -> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
 which I didn't understand which point it's trying to say.

by the way I'm using netbeans as IDE and it's not recognizing any error in my code.

please help me.

Comment: Might be caused by *java.util.Base64* being Java 8 only. Try to see if your OpenShift instance does support that language level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first place, I have to thank [Tome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2169091/tome).

the problem is for java.util.Base64 (it's only for java 8).

I tried to change the default version of JDK in my cartridge to 1.8.0 (because it has it by default).

I used this tutorial [JDK 8 support at DIY cartridge in OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894323/jdk-8-support-at-diy-cartridge-in-openshift) but it's not good enough for me.

I also change :

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

to :

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

but it cause some other errors.

so because I didn't have enough time , I just change my tools.java to :

```
package RestApi.Tools;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.Base64;


/**
 *  @file tools.java
 *  @brief this file contains some hasher like MD5.
 *  for decoding base 64 we had to use an library because java.util.Base64 
 *  is for jdk 8 and our server working with jdk 7.
 *
 *  @author Seyed Ali Roshan
 */
public class tools {
    
    public String md5(String text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(text.getBytes());

        byte byteData[] = md.digest();
        

        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0;i<byteData.length;i++) {
            String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xff & byteData[i]);
            if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append('0');
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    }
    
    public String[] conventToUserPass(String text) {
        String patternText = "(?i)Basic ";
        String hashedString = text.replaceFirst(patternText, "");
        
        byte[] unhased = Base64.decode(hashedString.getBytes());
        String finalText = new String(unhased);
        
        return finalText.split(":");
    } 
}
```

at the end I saw this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32748828/6442877
and when I search about wildfly, I decide to use it in feature.